# Where can I find the names of the various settings dialogs?

Tags: system-settings

I'm using xmonad, so I can't see the regular Ubuntu menu to get to the tools in the settings and preferences menus. I have to invoke them by name. Does anyone have a list of the names of these tools? (so that they could be started from the command line)

In particular, I need the Network Proxy Settings tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can access them by running `gnome-control-center`. Many of them are not separate applications, but are modules which are embedded in the control center directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly open the Network Proxy Settings tool, with the following command,
`gnome-control-center network`